# "Setting up profile generation failed"

Tags: xcode, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

Xcode 7.3.1 is giving me this error when I try and run my UI tests:

[image]

The text is:

```
Setting up profile generation failed

Xcode could not generate profile information for bundle identifier (com.apple.test.XXXXXXXXUITests-Runner). The profile path was missing. The environment variables were valid.
```

Has anyone got any idea what might be causing this or how to fix it?

Comment: I am getting the same thing. I am currently blaming it on Xcode 8 install. I am curious if this showed up for you after installing 8 on you computer.

Comment: Yes, it did—I also said `xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app` on the command line. Try undoing that and see if that gets you anywhere.